# Are Muslims allowed to work for Clinical Trial organizations?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, science, medical

My question is not based on discussions, want i want here is to completely understand the picture of Clinical Trials in Islam. My question is can a Muslim work in Research department or back end IT department for such organisations, would it be a Halal income?

Thank you in advance for your time and consideration.

Comment: You can improve your question and make it more answerable by expanding or including a link to explain why you think it is prohibited or the opinion of a scholar. I have a feeling it may be prohibited because in the past companies who ran those trials exploited the local populations.

Comment: @Ansari:I have made it simple. I had no evidence proving that.

Comment: As it is currently worded, this question is a good candidate for closing. Unless you can provide some connection between clinical trials and Islam or some reason to suggest it is not allowed, this is not a good answerable question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see what is wrong about Clinical Trials to be prohibited in Islam.

In Egypt we have a government-based company called [Vacsera](http://www.vacsera.com/). In this company they do drug trials on volunteers before releasing the drugs to public.

Comment: Please cite some references to prove your point. This looks like your personal opinion. Such answers are discouraged on this site.

Comment: This answer is of type "Useless negative" answers. There is no reference which talks about things which is halal. There is a list of Haram things, every thing else is halal. http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/355/the-useless-negative-problem

Comment: Regardless, you must seek out and cite some evidence, even though it may be difficult to do so. Even if it's general principles on halal/haram that are mentioned in fatawa about this issue.